# Using Tensorflow 2.0 and eager execution without Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, eager-execution, mlp

So this question might stem from a lack of knowledge about tensorflow. But I am trying to build a multilayer perceptron with `tensorflow 2.0`, but without `Keras`.

The reason being that it is a requirement for my machine learning course that we do not use keras. Why you might ask? I am not sure.

I already have implemented our model in `tensorflow 2.0` with Keras ease, and now I want to do the exact same thing without `keras`.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=784))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X[:7000]
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y[:7000], num_classes=5)
X_dev = X[7000:]
y_dev = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y[7000:], num_classes=5)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(X_dev, y_dev, batch_size=128)
print(score)
```

Here is my problem. Whenever I look up the documentation on `Tensorflow 2.0`, then even the guides on custom training are using Keras.

As placeholders and sessions are a thing of the past in `tensorflow 2.0`, as I understand it, then I am a bit unsure of how to structure it.

I can make tensor objects. I have the impression that I need to use eager execution and use gradient tape. But I still am unsure of how to put these things together.

Now my question is. Where should I look to get a better understanding? Which direction has the greatest descent?

Please do tell me if I am doing this stack overflow post wrong. It is my first time here.

Comment: This is the closest I have been to a real explaination of making a model without keras. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function

Comment: Is the idea to make a custom training loop or does the teacher want you to avoid layers and create the weights yourself?

Comment: There used to be tensorflow layers in the past (not keras layers), maybe you could use them plus the custom training loop.

Comment: Custom training loops: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Comment: Does the course instructor know that nowadays keras is built into tensorflow and is an integral part of most model-building?

Comment: I have now gone as far as to make the custom training loop. Though I still rely on a Keras model. ex 
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

Thanks Daniel for the link!

Comment: He sadly does not. He is using python 2.7 and tensorflow 1.14. Not that this is a problem, but this is the reason why he stated keras was not to be used :/

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Möller stated, there are these tutorials for [custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough) and [custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) on the official TensorFlow page. As stated on the custom training page:

> This tutorial used *tf.Variable* to build and train a simple linear model.

There is also this [blog](https://becominghuman.ai/image-classification-with-tensorflow-2-0-without-keras-e6534adddab2) that creates custom layers and training without Keras API. You can check this [code](http://colab.research.google.com/github/LAVI-USP/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Deep%20Learning/Classifiers/CNN_cifar10_TF2.ipynb) on Google Colab, which uses Cifar-10 with custom layers and training in the same manner.

Comment: First link is broken